# Git merge commit contains no delete but actually deletes?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch

Please help me understand.

I have branch develop, with files e.g **a.txt**, **b.txt**.

From it made branch **branch1** and **branch2**

**branch1** got new change(*unwanted*) added **c.txt** and **d.txt** (wanted)

**branch2** got new change added **c.txt** (wanted) and **e.txt**(wanted)

Merged **branch1** to develop but **unstaged c.txt** (*it should not be on develop*). Changeset shows only wanted changes, not **delete c.txt** or something. So now develop has **a.txt, b.txt and d.txt**

Then merged develop into **branch2** and here **c.txt** is deleted and can't understand why.

Idea is that, I **branch1** got updates which should only be in **branch2**. But when I unstage this unwanted changes and merge it to develop, updates from develop in **branch2** removes **c.txt**.

Please tell me why.

Comment: When I do what you say you did, c.txt isn't deleted.

Comment: Hm, one question, if in changset of merge commit I don't see delete something, is there any case that it deletes anyway?

Comment: Commits—including merge commits—hold full snapshots, not changes. If you attempt to view a commit *as* changes, Git compares the commit's snapshot to the commit's parent's snapshot. That works for ordinary commits, which have only one parent, but not for merge commits, which—by definition—have two or more parents. As a result, if you try to view a merge as a diff, you can't actually do it unless you pick *one* parent, and then the diff you see is only for *that parent*, not for the other parent.

Comment: When you say *file c.txt is deleted*, it's deleted *with respect to what?* Once you answer that question for yourself, the rest falls into place.